# Can SE replace the General Development List?

Tags: discussion

Given that the intention of the General dev list is for developers using the Joomla CMS to get help with problems, is it possible to deprecate that list and use SX instead?

Comment: Hard to say, I have a subscription of the but I don't read it because there is too much traffic on it. But I'm pretty sure there are many people who likes the list or the forum then SE. I personally like SE because it reduces the traffic to the important thing. Q&A. and its an archive.

Comment: Just throwing it out there. The Q&A style would suit a lot of the questions that are raised on General.

Comment: Some prefer to answer by email. Not me :)

Comment: This is a great question. I like the subscription to the dev list but it is easy to overlook because of traffic. As an attempting dev I am used to the question answer structure of SX and run here for many basic parts of a stack. As a joomla specific SX it might be helpful to tag user type ??s because many solutions or challenges are met by varying viewpoints.

Comment: I'm not sure that I would be ready to push for that to happen right now, but I definitely hope that it happens organically over the next 3-6 months.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can replace it. But we will see. If we see that the mailing list doesn't get used anymore (or only rarely) after this site is live, then I'm happy to close it. Time will tell us here.

Answer (score 2):

**It can replace some of the questions being asked there**, especially when it comes to technical advice.

The group is good for having discussions but unfortunately bad for sharing knowledge, making the information very hard to find. I can't count how many posts start with a title like "Need help" & co. and then a more senior member shares it's knowledge.

I think a lot of new users at Stack Exchange don't understand the concept behind and see it as a forum (as unfortunately many users leave very short answers).

Comment: To share knowledge, you can ask and answer a question at the same time to dump some knowledge. You can also mark a question as [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) to allow easier editing.
As for bad questions/answers - down vote them.